# Schedule an Oozie workflow at two different frequencies

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have an Oozie job that processes data incrementally. Going forward, I would like to run this job on an hourly basis to prepare the results as soon as possible. But to backfill old data, it would be faster to run sequential jobs processing a week's worth of data at a time.

Is it possible to have a single `coordinator.xml` file that allows for both of these modes, and simply choose between them based on a flag specified ad-hoc when the job is scheduled?

In the parameters of the `<coordinator-app>` tag in `coordinator.xml`, there is a single frequency, which suggests that this is not possible, at least not in a natural way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual solution was to create the workflow at a given frequency (say, daily), and then create a second "backfill" workflow with a different frequency (weekly or monthly) that calls the original workflow as a [sub-workflow](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Sub-workflow_Action).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do different frequencies within a coordinator. Based on your description you would not need the weekly job after the backfill happens.
I imagine you'd have to change the parameterization of the workflow as well to process more or less data.

On the other hand, you could just start the coordinator in the past with the frequency you'd like and tweak parameters like concurrency, throttle and execution [in the app definition](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.3._Synchronous_Coordinator_Application_Definition) so Oozie can chew through the backlog by executing the workflow in parallel.

Comment: The incremental nature of the data processing means that each workflow has to execute in order, which means they can't safely be executed in parallel. You are correct that the weekly job would no longer need to run once the backfill was finished, and yes, the workflow would have to be parameterized. I'm probably overcomplicating things here. :)